# pytest assert for pyspark dataframe comparison

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, pytest

I have 2 pyspark dataframe as shown in file attached. expected_df and actual_df

[image]

In my unit test I am trying to check if both are equal or not.

for which my code is

```
expected = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), expected_df.collect()) 
actual = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), actaual_df.collect()) 
assert expected = actual
```

Since both dfs are same but row order is different so assert fails here.
What is best way to compare such dfs.

Comment: have you tried sorting them

Comment: I could sort based on 'period_start_time' but is there not any method of comparing without doing same.

Answer (score 12):

You can try `pyspark-test`

https://pypi.org/project/pyspark-test/

This is inspired by the panadas testing module build for pyspark.

Usage is simple

```py
from pyspark_test import assert_pyspark_df_equal

assert_pyspark_df_equal(df_1, df_2)
```

Also apart from just comparing dataframe, just like the pandas testing module it also accepts many optional params that you can check in the documentation.

Note:

1. The datatypes in pandas and pysaprk are bit different, thats why directly converting to `.toPandas` and using panadas testing module might not be the right approach.
2. This package is for unit/integration testing, so meant to be used with small size dfs

Comment: This lib does not scale. For small datasets we can use pd.testing.assert_frame_equal.

Answer (score 3):

This is done in some of the pyspark documentation:

`assert sorted(expected_df.collect()) == sorted(actaual_df.collect())`

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by hashing each row with Spark's hash function and then summing the resultant column.

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def hash_df(df):
    """Hashes a DataFrame for comparison.

    Arguments:
        df (DataFrame): A dataframe to generate a hash from

    Returns:
        int: Summed value of hashed rows of an input DataFrame
    """
    # Hash every row into a new hash column
    df = df.withColumn('hash_value', F.hash(*sorted(df.columns))).select('hash_value')

    # Sum the hashes, see https://shortest.link/28YE
    value = df.agg(F.sum('hash_value')).collect()[0][0]

    return value

expected_hash = hash_df(expected_df)
actual_hash = hash_df(actual_df)
assert expected_hash == actual_hash
```

Comment: +1 for creativity. and i imagine that while probability of a hash collision increases with the number of columns in the pyspark dataframe, it's essentially 0 for almost all situations

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done without applying sort on any of the columns(specially on the key column), reason being there isn't any [guarantee for ordering of records in a DataFrame](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207) . You cannot predict the order in which the records are going to appear in the dataframe. The below approach works fine for me:

```
expected = expected_df.orderBy('period_start_time').collect()
actual = actaual_df.orderBy('period_start_time').collect() 
assert expected == actual
```

Answer (score 0):

If the overhead of an additional library such as `pyspark_test` is a problem, you could try sorting both dataframes by the same columns, converting them to pandas, and using `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal`.

I know that the `.toPandas` method for pyspark dataframes is generally discouraged because the data is loaded into the driver's memory (see the pyspark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html)), but this solution works for relatively small unit tests.

For example:

```
sort_cols = actual_df.columns

pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(
    actual_df.sort(sort_cols).toPandas(),
    expected_df.sort(sort_cols).toPandas()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [chispa](https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa) package.

```
from chispa.dataframe_comparer import assert_df_equality

assert_df_equality(actual_df, expected_df, ignore_row_order=True)
```

You can also ignore the column order and set other arguments. Here is a quick look at the function signature.

```
Signature:
assert_df_equality(
    df1,
    df2,
    ignore_nullable=False,
    transforms=None,
    allow_nan_equality=False,
    ignore_column_order=False,
    ignore_row_order=False,
    underline_cells=False,
    ignore_metadata=False,
)
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://mrpowers.github.io/chispa/#ignore-row-order).

Answer (score 0):

As of `3.5.0`, Spark has included `assert_pyspark_df_equal` in `pyspark.testing`; you can read more about it [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.testing.assertDataFrameEqual.html).

Answer (score -1):

I have two Dataframes with the same order.
Comparing this two I use:

```
def test_df(df1, df2):
    assert df1.values.tolist() == df2.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score -2):

try to have "==" instead of "=". 
assert expected == actual

Answer (score -4):

Another way go about that ensuring sort order would be:

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

def assert_frame_with_sort(results, expected, key_columns):
    results_sorted = results.sort_values(by=key_columns).reset_index(drop=True)
    expected_sorted = expected.sort_values(by=key_columns).reset_index(drop=True)
    assert_frame_equal(results_sorted, expected_sorted)
```

Comment: That's for pandas DataFrame objects, not Spark DataFrame.